# Can I programatically run a Zeppelin notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have Zeppelin on top of Hadoop with a Spark cluster.

I'd like to run the first five paragraphs in one note, then the first five paragraphs in a separate note. I don't want them to run at the same time because they have objects with the same names.

Also, the machine cues them up, so they will in effect run sequentially.

Can I run code to say `run the first five in note abc` and afterward `run the first five in note zxy`?

Comment: The job scheduler embedded in Zeppelin _(quark)_ is a mess. If you are serious about Operations, then run your scripts via a regular scheduler (even CRON) and Livy REST API. But that requires some development because of the REST API syntax and its asynchronous nature (i.e. submit the script, retrieve the job ID, then poll until it reaches success or failure status).

Comment: According to the docs, I can also use `run.note(<note_id>)`

Answer (score 2):

In Zeppelin, there is a [Notebook API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html), that you can use to fetch the list of paragraphs in the notebook (for example via [paragraph status API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html#get-the-status-of-all-paragraphs) or via [Note information API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html#get-an-existing-note-information)), and then for execution of paragraphs one by one via [synchronous paragraph execution API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html#run-a-paragraph-synchronously).